# Fisher information of poisson distributed random variable

Tags: statistics, random-variables, proof-explanation, expected-value, fisher-information

> Let's consider a printer queue. We know that the expected number of printer jobs almost obeys a Poisson distribution, so $P_{\vartheta}(X=k)=e^{-\vartheta}\frac{\vartheta^k}{k!}$, where $\vartheta\in]0,\infty[$. We estimate the expected number of printer jobs $\vartheta$ by $\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i$. Compute the Fisher information $I(\vartheta):=\mathbb{E}_{\vartheta}\left(\left(\frac{d\ln(P_{\vartheta}(X))}{d\vartheta}\right)^2\right)$.

We know that if $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ are independent random variables with a distribution like $P_X(\vartheta)=f(X_1,\vartheta)\dots f(X_n,\vartheta)$, then

$$\mathbb{E}_{\vartheta}\left(\left(\frac{d\ln(P_{\vartheta}(X))}{d\vartheta}\right)^2\right)=n\cdot \mathbb{E}_{\vartheta}\left(\left(\frac{d\ln(P_{\vartheta}(X_i))}{d\vartheta}\right)^2\right).$$

If we consider the $n$-many independent observations $X:=(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ , where each $X_i$ is the number of printer jobs in a certain period of time, the probability is given by
\begin{align*} 
&P_{\vartheta}(\{X=(x_1,\dots,x_n)\})=P_{\vartheta}(\{X_1=x_1\})\cdots P_{\vartheta}(\{X_n=x_n\})\\ 
&=\frac{e^{-\vartheta}\vartheta^{x_1}}{(x_1!)}\dots \frac{e^{-\vartheta}\vartheta^{x_n}}{(x_n!)}=\frac{e^{-n\vartheta}\vartheta^{\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i}}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^n(x_i!)}. 
\end{align*}

Applying the above statement yields after some manipulations $I(\vartheta)=\frac{n}{\vartheta}$.

However, the sample solution says:

\begin{align*}
&I(\vartheta)=\sum\limits_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\frac{d\ln(P_{\vartheta}(X))}{d\vartheta}\right)^2}{P_{\vartheta}(X)}=\sum\limits_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x!}e^{\vartheta}\vartheta^{-x}\left(-e^{-\vartheta}\vartheta^x+e^{-\vartheta}x\vartheta^{x-1}\right)\\
&= \sum\limits_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac{\vartheta^x}{x!}e^{-\vartheta}\left(\frac{x}{\vartheta}-1\right)^2=\mathbb{V}(X)\frac{1}{\vartheta}^2=\frac{1}{\vartheta}.
\end{align*}

This makes no sense to me? Why $x\to\infty$ and why is there only one random variable instead of a vector which represents $n$-many obersavtions?

Comment: You computed $I_n(\theta) = nI(\theta)$. $I(\theta)$ is what people mean by fisher information.

Comment: @AndrewZhang, I don't exactly understand what you mean, maybe you can elaborate a bit. From what I understand the fisher information is defined with regard to a family of probability measures that refer to a random variable $X$. Howevr, in this particular case the random variable $X$ happens to be a vector of some random variables. What I computed is still $I(\theta)$ with reagrd to $X$.

Comment: $I_n(\theta)$ is the variance of the score function, where the likelihood is computed from $n$ samples. However, people generally write this as $nI(\theta)$, since this makes clear the variance reduction from more samples.

Answer (score 1):

The Fisher information for all $N$ samples simplifies to $N$ times the Fisher information of a single sample.
The score function is
$l(\vartheta|x)
= -\vartheta + x\log \vartheta,
l'(\vartheta|x)
= \frac{x}{\vartheta}-1,
$

To compute Fisher information (of a single sample), we must compute the expectation over $X$ (hence the infinite sum)
$$
I(\vartheta)
=\mathbb{E} \left[ l'(\vartheta|x)^2 \right]
=\sum_{k\ge 0}
P_{\vartheta}(X=k)
\left( \frac{k}{\vartheta}-1 \right)^2
=\mathbb{V}
\left( \frac{X}{\vartheta} \right)
=\frac{1}{\vartheta^2} 
\mathbb{V} \left( X \right)
=\frac{1}{\vartheta}
$$

Comment: Ah ok at least this answer why $x\to\infty$.  Regarding the other issue I conclude from your answer that the sample solution is wrong as it only provides the Fisher information of a single sample and not of all samples.